# Magento Value '29,990000' has to be numeric

Tags: admin, php

I just updated my zendserver. then when I tried to access /admin on my magento local I get the following error `Value '29,990000' has to be numeric`

I tried to replace

`$price = sprintf("%f", $price);`

with

```
$price = (float) $price;
```

in `app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php`
but the above didn't work at all.

Then I tried to change "precision = 14" to "precision = 8" in my php.ini
but still I could find a solution on this issue

Comment: In which file & line does the error occur, and where does the number come from?

Comment: Check your locale settings (system wide and in php.ini), looks like the settings for number format are wrong for Magento

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved this by downgrading my PHP from PHP 5.5 to 5.3

Comment: That's not a satisfying solution. Don't run PHP 5.3 in production anymore, its lifetime has ended over a year ago (i.e. no security updates)